# Query Builder with join and condition in Many to many relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.3

I have a many to many relation with Employee and MembreFamille. And i want to get all MembreFamilles that have an Employee.
This is my query  :

```
class MembreFamilleRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getMembres($emp)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
        $qb
            ->leftJoin('a.employees', 'employees');
        $qb
            ->where('employees.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $emp);
        return $qb
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
    }
}
```

When I test this function in the controller , the function return 0 result.

The mapping in Employee Entity:

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PFE\EmployeesBundle\Entity\MembreFamille", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $membreFamilles;
```

The Mapping in MembreFamille Entity :

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PFE\UserBundle\Entity\Employee", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $employees;
```

The use in the Controller ($employee is an instance of Employee Entity ) :

```
$list = $em->getRepository('PFEEmployeesBundle:MembreFamille')->getMembres($employee->getId());
```

Comment: $emp is an integer? Can you also please show us the mapping between employee and membreFamilie?

Comment: Yes $emp is an integer.

Comment: It seems that your query is fetching every MembreFamille that has an employee whose id is $emp, and not every MembreFamille that has an employee (any of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a JoinTable for your ManyToMany association and set the owning and inverse sides:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PFE\EmployeesBundle\Entity\MembreFamille",
 *   cascade={"persist"}, mapped="employees")
 */
private $membreFamilles;


.................................


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PFE\UserBundle\Entity\Employee", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="membreFamilles")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="membre_familles_employees")
 */
private $employees;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a construction called "MEMBER OF".

```
class MembreFamilleRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getMembres($emp)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
            ->where(':employee MEMBER OF a.employees')
            ->setParameter('employee', $emp)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
}
```

You can use a construction called "MEMBER OF"